# Changing the Excel 2013 Sheet Selector to a Vertical Orientation

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Is it possible, and if so, what is the best way to change the orientation of the sheet selector bar at the bottom of the window in Excel 2013 to be vertical rather than horizontal? I have a large number of sheets, and a different orientation would make selecting them easier.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of any feature like this and can't see it anywhere in the settings - I doubt this is currently possible in Excel 2013. I'd suggest either reducing the length of your sheet names, or else look at combining tabs to improve efficiency.

Think of it like a Database - unless sheets are all displaying distinctly different types of data, it's good to hold all their data on one sheet. If you have twelve different sheets showing twelve months of data, I'd consider making one annual sheet and a dynamic monthly sheet that can retrieve a month's data at a time as you need it to.